# Why I need to have a primary key of a child table as a foreign key of a parent table and not vice versa for 1:1 identified relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

trying to understand a DB concepts and ran into this question.
Identify relationship is when a parent table pk is child table fk. For example, I have a `person` table and `ssn` table. `ssn` cannot exist without a `person` and a `person` can have only 1 `ssn` and `ssn` can belong to only 1 person so it should be 1:1 identified relationship.

Question #1: Whey do I need to make `person_id` as a primary key on `SSN` table if I can uniquely identity `ssn` since it's already unique?
When I set `person_id` in `SSN` table as a foreign key of `id` in `Person` table my SQl workbench creates 1:n relationship. However, it's is not accurate since a person can have only 1 ssn(picture 1)

Question #2 - Why does it happen since it can be 1:1 relationship as well and I can query ssn based on person_id fk easily
If I reamove the person_id from SSN table as a primary key the relationship becomes unidentified (picture 2)

Question #3 - why is it happening since I
still can uniquely identified ssn without person_id field

If I use a workbench to create 1:1 identity relationship it creates a foreign key in the `PERSON` table, hence making it a child table and `SSN` a parent table which is not accurate as well
I know that people suggest just simply place a data into a parent table when there is 1:1 identify relationship but what if for example a table already has 20 fields and adding another 20 fields would make it super big, wouldn't be easy to create a separate table and link them into 1:1 relationship (picture 3)

Question #4: It's pretty easy to memorize - if 1:1 set parent table fk as child table pk and if 1:n - set child table fk as parent table pk but I want to understand what is the logic behind it?
Thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmDW3.png)

Comment: IF it's 1:1, why do you have a separate `ssn` table? Isn't `ssn` just an attribute of `person`?

Comment: *Whey do I need to make person_id as a primary key on SSN table if I can uniquely identity ssn since it's already unique?* o_O you do not need this.

Comment: Unless there's a lot of additional data in the ssn table, this problem can be solved by making ssn a column of person with a [unique index](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/).

Answer (score 1):

If it’s 1:1 there is no “parent” or “child” - they are “siblings” of each other.

The requirement as per question title is there because without the reverse foreign key, it would not be 1:1 but would be 1:0..* (one to many).

To guarantee 1:1 both sides *must* exist and the way to do that is with bidirectional FKs.